# TST, AND operation in ARM assembly. Why is only the LSBit considered?

Tags: assembly, arm, logical-operators

In reference to ARM assembly:

I have some confusion regarding the TST operation in the following lines of code which test to see if a number is even or odd:

```
mov R0, #167

TST R0, #1 //AND operation 
addeq ... //add if even
addne ... //add if not even
```

My question is why is the TSt operation only considering the least significant bit (LSB) to figure out if the number is even or not, and not looking at the rest of the bits in #167 (which has LSB's 0111)

Since TST 167,1 would AND 167 and 1 which would AND LSB's (0111 and 0001), and even though the LSB would AND to =1, wouldn't ANDing the 2nd LSB cause the TST operation to output 0?

Comment: ANDing with 1, only the (single) LSB of R0 is tested because all the other bits of "1" are zeroes - the non-LSBs of R0 _cannot_ affect the result

Comment: `0x000000a7 & 0x00000001 == 0x00000001 (!= 0)` - that's all there is to it. I don't understand the premise of what's being asked here... :/

Comment: "Why is only the LSBit considered?": because it's the parity bit.

Answer (score 3):

To test if a number in binary is even or odd, all you need to do is check the rightmost (least significant) bit. The other bits don't matter, since all of their "values" are non-zero powers of two, i.e. even numbers.

Adding even numbers together will never produce an odd number, so they don't matter.

The result of bitwise-ANDing 167 and 1 is 1, which is not zero. Not sure why you worry so much about the rest of the bits, since the second argument to the bitwise AND is just 1, no other bits than the LSB matter (they will all be masked off and forced to 0 in the implicit result).

Comment: I see, I forgot that only 1 AND 1 = 1, otherwise any existence of zero when ANDING the rest of the bits will result in a 0, and since #1 = 0001, the non-LSB are all zero and therefore anything ANDed with them will also be zero. Thanks.

Comment: In base 10 to know if a number is divisible by 10 you look to see if the least significant digit is zero.  In base 10 to see if a number is even or odd you look at the least significant digit to see if it is even or odd.  In base 2 the same deal, is the least significant digit even (0) or odd (1).  Base 8, base 16 all the same any base that even should follow the same rule, would have to think about bases that are odd.

Answer (score 0):

The Z flag is set based on the entire result being either zero or not.  i.e. it's a horizontal OR of all the bits in `167 & 1`.

If you want 32 separate per-bit zero-or-not results, you use an AND and look at the integer register result, not the flag result.